# How to define that a class has to declare a shared method

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, shared

I have several classes that inherit from a base class. Let's call it `Zoo`.
All derived classes should declare one same method `Species` which returns a List of species in this kind of zoo.

Inheritance and MustOverride is what I normally would do:

```
Public Class Species

    Public Sub New(name As String)
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub
    Public Property Name() As String

End Class
```

Base class:

```
Public MustInherit Class Zoo

    Public MustOverride Function Species() As List(Of Species)

End Class
```

Derived classes:

```
Public Class WaterZoo
    Inherits Zoo

    Public Overrides Function Species() As List(Of Species)
        Dim list As New List(Of Species)
        list.Add(New Species("whale"))
        list.Add(New Species("shark"))
        list.Add(New Species("dolphin"))

        Return list
    End Function
End Class

Public Class DesertZoo
    Inherits Zoo

    Public Overrides Function Species() As List(Of Species)
        Dim list As New List(Of Species)
        list.Add(New Species("lion"))
        list.Add(New Species("giraffe"))
        list.Add(New Species("antelope"))

        Return list
    End Function

End Class
```

Now, i could work with this classes like this:

```
Public Class Main

    Public Shared Sub Main(args() As String)
        Dim zoo1 As New WaterZoo
        Dim zoo2 As New DesertZoo

        Dim species1 = zoo1.Species()
        Dim species2 = zoo2.Species()

        Dim allSpecies = species1.Concat(species2)

        For Each s In allSpecies
            Debug.Print(s.Name)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

But what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
 Dim species1 = WaterZoo.Species()
 Dim species2 = DesertZoo.Species()
```

I want the `Species`-method to be shared (static in C#), because the actual class design is a lot more complex and I don't want to create an instance just for getting this one list.

The problem here is, you can't declare a `MustOverride Shared` (virtual static in C#) method, which makes sense.

**But how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?**

Comment: So, if you already know `WaterZoo` and `DesertZoo` at compile time, why do you need the `Species` method to be `MustOverride`?

Comment: @sloth I'm not sure if I got your question right. I just want to make sure every derived class of `Zoo` defines the method `Species`.